# Filter queryset on a foreignkey

Tags: python, django

It might be not new to all and need your expert guidance. I am trying to filter a column on a django-table2. Note I have not used django-filter here.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True)

class Control(models.Model):
   published = models.charField(auto_now=False)
   group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I am trying to filter in views.py as below

```
table = ControlTable(Control.objects.all().order_by('-published').filter(
            group__in=form['contact'].value(),
        )
```

Issue is this is working fine, but when selecting '-----' from dropdown then its showing blank table instead of all the values.
Again if I change the query filter as below

```
table = ControlTable(Control.objects.all().order_by('-published').filter(
                Group__title__iexact=form['contact'].value(),
            )
```

then throwing error `Cannot resolve keyword 'Group' into field.`

Could you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes sense, if you select `----`, then it uses `None`, so you are filtering for `None`. You should check for that:

```
items = ControlTable(Control.objects.all().order_by('-published')
group = form['contact'].value()
if group:
    items = items.filter(
        group__in=group
    )
table = items
```